# iOS SDK, how to send a message to specific people?

Tags: ios, facebook

Is it possible (using the iOS SDK ) to send a message to a pre-known list of people? I'm using this syntax, from (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog):

```
[FBDialogs presentMessageDialogWithLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/"] 
                            handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                              if(error) {
                                // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error messaging link: %@", error.description]);
                              } else {
                                // Success
                                NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                              }
                            }];
```

From what I can tell, some usages of the share dialog support a to: parameter, but I don't see that here.

Edit: **It really seems like the user picker dialog is not meant to be used in conjunction with the other messaging / sharing features of the SDK. This seems like a kind of absurd oversight.**

Thanks!

Comment: Where does it say that the message dialog support a to parameter?

Comment: It doesn't -- and neither do I :). I said "some usages of the share dialog" which is a different usage than the message dialog...

Comment: Ok, the answer is that you can't it is up to the user to select who they want to send the message to

Comment: I'm hoping there's more to the story than that :).